# Подскажите функцию для экранирования

Tags: python

В общем, нужна функция, которая будет экранировать символы. Точно так же как и ``. Есть ли она в питоне? И есть ли функция, которая делает обратную операцию?
Пример:

```
"\x62\141\x73\145\x36\64\x5f\144\x65\143\x6f\144\x65" -> 'base64_decode'`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> b"\x62\141\x73\145\x36\64\x5f\144\x65\143\x6f\144\x65".decode()
'base64_decode'
>>> 'base64_decode'.encode()
b'base64_decode'
```

b - объект класса bytes

Comment: Спасибо. Наградил.

Answer (score 0):

Глядите сюда: [codec registry and base classes](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html).

Comment: Мне кажется, вот так и надо всегда отвечать... и не ошибешься и вопрошающего к RTFM приучишь :)

Comment: 2 FoxManiac - а зачем тогда этот ресурс?может просто - взять этот домен,вставить форму поиска и перенаправлять все вопросы в гугл?имхо: за перенаправление на другие ресурсы,я бы - банил,что я и буду делать в своем проекте

Comment: Зачем банить? Мне кажется, что сперва люди смотрят в поиске, а если не находят, то уже идут сюда.

Comment: При прочих равных условиях качество вопроса и ответа выигрывает от самодостаточности: [внешние зависимости](http://blog.hashcode.ru/2011/03/blog-post_12.html).

Comment: Спасибо. Наградил.